# replace two values of a row with one in R dataframe

Tags: r

It may be very simple task but am having trouble in doing this. sorry if it is a silly question but am asking here after so many attempts.

i have 399 files named prediction1, prediction2, ..... so on, and each file containing two values like

in file predition1

0.1234
-1.2345

in file prediction2

-1.5443
0.34436

..... so on

these files are imported in to R using

```
filelist = list.files(pattern = "pred*")
myfiles = lapply(filelist, read.table)
```

and the list object "myfiles" is converted into dataframe using:

```
myfiles2 = as.data.frame(myfiles)
```

now myfiles2 contains:

```
> myfiles2[1]
  V1
1 -1
2 -1
```

up to 399 times.

now i have to apply some conditions like `if(myfiles2[1][1,]>0 & myfiles2[1][2,]<0)` then`replace the values with numeric "1001" and`if(myfiles2[1][1,]<0 & myfiles2[1][2,]>0)` then replace the values with numeric with "0110"..

can anyone suggest me right way to do this, actually i am able to print the values in R console but not getting values in any object so that i can merge all to make one matrix.

i hope discussed my problem better than previous.

```
for(i in 1:399)
{
ab = NULL;
    if(myfiles2[i][1,]>0 & myfiles2[i][2,]<0)
    {
    myfiles2[i] = "1001"    
    } 
        if(myfiles2[i][1,]>0 & myfiles2[i][2,])>0)
        {
        myfiles2[i] = "1010"

        } 
    if(myfiles2[i][1,]<0 & myfiles2[i][2,]<0)
    {
        myfiles2[i] = "0101"
    } 
        else 
        {
        myfiles2[i] = "0110"
        }
ab = append(ab, myfiles[i])
}
```

this is the code i am using and getting last replaced value, basically appending is the problem i think

Comment: What is the dimension of `myfiles2`?

Comment: "V1"     "V1.1"   "V1.2"   "V1.3"   "V1.4"   "V1.5"   "V1.6"   "V1.7" upto V1.398 is dimnames and 2 399 is dimension

Comment: Your code and description is confusing.  Could you post a small example dataset with the expected result. ie. 4-5 columns, and 4-6 rows of the data

Comment: > myfiles2[1]
  V1
1 -1
2 -1 
as it its first row and second row are less than 0 i have to put 0110 at the place of -1 -1.

Comment: for(i in 1:399)
{
ab = NULL;
 if(myfiles2[i][1,]>0 & myfiles2[i][2,]<0)
 {
 myfiles2[i] = "1001" 
 } 
  if(myfiles2[i][1,]>0 & myfiles2[i][2,])>0)
  {
  myfiles2[i] = "1010"
  
  } 
 if(myfiles2[i][1,]<0 & myfiles2[i][2,]<0)
 {
        myfiles2[i] = "0101"
 } 
  else 
  {
  myfiles2[i] = "0110"
  }
ab = append(ab, myfiles[i])
}
i am using this code, actually i am having problem in appending. it is giving last replace value.

Comment: It is for the entire row?  Please do show it on the post as this is hard to read from the comments

Comment: accourding to dimension there are two two rows and 399 columns, basicly i have to replace these two rows with one new vale

Comment: I guess the condition is only based on the first column.  So, it becomes `FALSE`, the whole dataset will be replace by `1010` or else `0101`, right?

Comment: $V1.398
[1] "0101" "0101"
it is giving this output, in which first it is not appending second i want this value only 1 time, but it is giving according to the number of rows

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
d1 <- cbind(expand.grid(rep(list(c(-1,1)),2)),
         Var3=c('0101', '1001', '0110', '1010'),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
myfiles2[] <-  lapply(myfiles2, function(x) {
                    x[] <-d1[!colSums(t(d1[,-3])!=sign(x)),3]
                x})
myfiles2[1:3]
#    V1   V2   V3
#1 0110 1010 0110
#2 0110 1010 0110
```

#### data

```
 set.seed(22)
 myfiles2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100), nrow=2))
 myfiles2[1:3]
 #          V1        V2         V3
 #1 -0.5121391 1.0078262 -0.2089594
 #2  2.4851837 0.2928146  1.8580924
```

Comment: Error in sign(x) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function

Comment: @JyotiSharma  Please check the columns of your dataset to see if they are `numeric` class. ie.  `str(myfiles2)`. I created a dataset based on what you mentioned.  You can post the `dput` of subset of your dataset to find the problem.  ie. `dput(myfiles2[,1:5])`

Answer (score 0):

Try this for loading the data:

```
filelist = list.files(pattern = "pred*")
myfiles <- do.call('rbind', lapply(filelist, read.table))
```

That should go right to a data frame. Then this should make your new column.

```
myfiles$newcol <- ifelse(V1 > 0 & V2 < 0, 1001, NA)
myfiles$newcol <- ifelse(V1 > 0 & V2 > 0, 1010, newcol)
```

And so on, with your if statements.